# Why doesn't my NSUserDefault value get written?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsuserdefaults

I'm trying to make use of NSUserDefaults to keep track of some promotional data in my iOS app, but it's not working like I'm expecting it to.  Here's the code...

```
 NSString *promoID = [[[self currentPromo] allKeys] objectAtIndex:0];

 if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"promoid-%@", promoID]])
 {
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"promoid-%@", promoID]];
 .
 .
 .
```

Everytime this if statement is executed, the code inside is executed.  Shouldn't the code inside this if statement only execute once?

Thanks so much for your wisdom!

Comment: where you have written this if code? in which method? how are you calling it?

Comment: are you using setting bundle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on how fast you go through this again.

NSUserDefaults are not synchronized instantly. If you want to do this, you need to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after setting a value.

Comment: thank you, that fixed it!  I'll accept your answer as soon as the ten mins passes.  thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use synchronize keyword to retrieve your data in NSUserDefaults

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

This will retrieve and display the data.

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn't doing that and almost got crazy, tanks a lot!